# Resolve GOPATH value (Go 1.8+)

Tags: go, environment-variables, gopath

In Go 1.8+ the `GOPATH` environment variable is optional. When not set, `GOPATH` defaults to `$HOME/go`. Is there a variable or function in some standard library package that will show the final value of `GOPATH` (I'm hoping for something like [`runtime.GOROOT()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOROOT) even when it is inferred in the case that no `GOPATH` environment variable has been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GOPATH` doesn't technically exist in the runtime, it's only used by the build tools. `GOARCH`, `GOOS`, and `GOROOT` are the only variables recorded at compile time, but they still do not effect the execution of the runtime.

You can check for `GOPATH` in the environment, and fallback to `$HOME/go` if it's not there. However, this still doesn't guarantee that you're getting the `GOPATH` used to build the binary, since the application may not have been build by the same user, or even on the same system.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!